# How to retrieve Longitude and Latitude from database within a given radius?

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation

This is my database table (spots).

[image]

Given a point on map `P(longitude, latitude)`, what I want to retrieve from the database is the set of points within a given radius where `P` is the center. I tried a simple query using the simple formula of Longitude and Latitude, unfortunately the result is always null :( . What am I doing wrong here? Any idea?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name 
WHERE ACOS(SIN('".$latitude."') * SIN(spots.latitude) + COS('".$latitude."') * COS(spots.latitude) * COS(spots.longitude - '".$longitude    ."')) * 6371 <= '".$radius."'";
```

Comment: Try to see if this helps, Im not sure: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE ACOS(SIN($latitude) * SIN(spots.latitude) + COS($latitude) * COS(spots.latitude) * COS(spots.longitude - $longitude)) * 6371 <= $radius";`

Comment: [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) has great support for geo queries :-)

Comment: I'm confused. You ware trying to retrieve rows where the longitude & latitude are within a given radius?

Comment: @Dimme: You meant I don't need the extra single quotes?

Comment: @MrGlass: Yes, I just realize I interpreted my question badly. Edited.

Comment: start by making a valid query in phpmyadmin(you're using it I see) and verifying results. Then, *and only then*, should you involve php and try to make the query dynamically. This is a generic debugging strategy, where you simplify things to help you narrow in on the problem.

Comment: Yeap Chan, you don't need them.

Comment: @Dimme: It still doesn't work :(. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Here you have a complete tutorial about your question. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Cameron S's & MrGlass's ideas, and a bit searching over the Internet, I found one working solution:

```
$R = 6371;
$max_lat = $lat + rad2deg($r/$R);
$min_lat = $lat - rad2deg($r/$R);

$max_lon = $lon + rad2deg($r/$R/cos(deg2rad($lat)));
$min_lon = $lon - rad2deg($r/$R/cos(deg2rad($lat)));
$lat = deg2rad($lat);
$lon = deg2rad($lon);

$sql = "
select id, name, description, latitude, longitude, 
       acos(sin($lat)*sin(radians(latitude)) + cos($lat)*cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude)-$lon)) * $R as D
from (
  select id, name, description, latitude, longitude 
  from $tbl_name 
  where latitude > $min_lat and latitude < $max_lat
    and longitude > $min_lon and longitude < $max_lon
  ) as first_cut 
where acos(sin($lat)*sin(radians(latitude)) + cos($lat)*cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude) - $lon)) * $R < $r
order by D";
```

Answer (score 4):

The way I would solve this problem is create a geographic "box", simply by choosing lat between lat + max lat distance using radius and lat - max lat distance (the same for longitude).

Then, I would calculate in PHP which of those points actually satisfy your criteria (the circle inscribed in the box) rather than perform a complex calculation on every row. This should make the calculation easier and increase performance.

Here is a C# example of the query (lon1 and lat1 being the center lat and lon). I am not proficient enough in PHP to create a PHP example and if someone would like to add one that would be great:

```
        double minLon = lon1 - maxDistance / Math.Abs(Math.Cos((lat1 / 180) * Math.PI) * 69);
        double maxLon = lon1 + maxDistance / Math.Abs(Math.Cos((lat1 / 180) * Math.PI) * 69);
        double minLat = lat1 - (maxDistance / 69);
        double maxLat = lat1 + (maxDistance / 69);
        String query = "SELECT [idColumn], [latitude], [longitude] FROM [db].[dbo].[table] WHERE [latitude] BETWEEN " + minLat + " AND " + maxLat + " AND [longitude] BETWEEN " + minLon + " AND " + maxLon;
```

And here is how I calculated the distance from these points:

```
        double r = 3956.087107103049;
        return (r * 2) * Math.Asin(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Math.Sin((lat1 - lat2) / 2), 2) + Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2) * Math.Pow(Math.Sin((lon1 - lon2) / 2), 2)));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Could you elaborate it by providing a brief example?

Comment: Yes, I added an example in C# that shows the query creation and later calculating actual distance.

Comment: Thank you for posting the example.

Comment: @Guarav, we can easily use the above Haversine formula to calculate the difference between two points (the last line), but we don't want to do that on all the points in the database since it's not necessary.
We can first select a *rectangle* around the *ellipse* we're testing for from the database by overestimating the range of lat/long. Then, for those points inside the rectangle, we actually run the full comparison.

Comment: Smart approach...I like it

Answer (score 0):

I would calculate the max/min possible values for latitude and longitude in PHP. Then, you can select all the locations within that range with pretty simple SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from locations where latitude >= $minLat and latitude <= $maxLat and longitude >= $minLong and longitude <= $maxLong
```

Comment: How would I calculate the max/min possible values for latitude and longitude? What's the formula should I use? By the way, thanks.

Comment: If you have a center long/lat and  radius, this is easy: $maxLong = $long + $radius; $minLong = $long - $radius; $maxLat = $lat + $radius; $minLat = $lat - $radius;

Comment: From my understanding, latitude and longitude are coordinate of a point on the sphere though. From my table, they are in degree, so finding max/min is not simple as +/- radius.

Comment: @Chan You are correct, you will need to use the logic from the first two lines of code in my example. A bit of math is required to change the radius to calculate a max longitude and latitude.